# How to Delete the Textbox dynamically in a DIV using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to Delete the TextBox in a DIV using javascript. First I created the four column in a div and I created the checkbox dynamically using the Add button in a div.

What is my problem is I need to delete the appropriate textbox using the Delete button (behind the textbox).

So please give me a solution to rectify it.

```js
function Add() {
  div1.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
  div2.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
  div3.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
  div4.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
}

function removeRow(input) {
  document.getElementById('div1').removeChild(input.parentNode);
}
```

```css
#Wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightblue;
}
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightyellow;
}
#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightgray;
}
#div4 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightblue;
}
#ClearFix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Add()">Add TextBox</button>
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="div1">
    <p>This is Div one</p>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <p>This is Div two</p>
  </div>

  <div id="div3">
    <p>This is Div threee</p>
  </div>

  <div id="div4">
    <p>This is Div Four</p>
  </div>

  <div id="ClearFix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u7gdatgj/

Comment: it is not working plz give me a solution

Comment: You have unresolved variables in Add() func: div1, div2, ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this working snippet.

```js
// Code goes here

function Add() {
  div1.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
  div2.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
  div3.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
  div4.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
}

function removeRow(input) {
  if(input.previousElementSibling.tagName == "INPUT"  && input.previousElementSibling.getAttribute("type") == "text") {
    var inputElement = input.previousElementSibling;
    var divId = input.parentNode.id;
    document.getElementById(divId).removeChild(inputElement);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#Wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightblue;
}
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightyellow;
}
#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightgray;
}
#div4 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightblue;
}
#ClearFix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <button onclick="Add()">Add TextBox</button>

  <div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
      <p>This is Div one</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
      <p>This is Div two</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
      <p>This is Div threee</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div4">
      <p>This is Div Four</p>
    </div>

    <div id="ClearFix"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your input and delete button in one container, lets say div.
Also pass a second parameter in the

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Dynamic Form</title>

    <style>

    #Wrapper
        {
            width:90%;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        #div1
        {
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            background:lightblue;
        }


        #div2
        {
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            background:lightyellow;
        }

        #div3
        {
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            background:lightgray;
        }

        #div4
        {
            float: left;
            width:20%;
            background:lightblue;
        }

        #ClearFix
        {
            clear:both;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <button onclick="Add()">Add TextBox</button>

    <div id="Wrapper">
        <div id="div1">
            <p>This is Div one</p>
        </div>

        <div id="div2">
            <p>This is Div two</p>
        </div>

        <div id="div3">
            <p>This is Div threee</p>
        </div>

        <div id="div4">
            <p>This is Div Four</p>
        </div>

        <div id="ClearFix"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function Add()
    {
        div1.innerHTML += "<br><br> <div><input type='text' name='mytext'>"+"<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this,this.parentNode.parentNode)'></div>";
        div2.innerHTML += "<br><br> <div><input type='text' name='mytext'>"+"<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this,this.parentNode.parentNode)'></div>";
        div3.innerHTML += "<br><br> <div><input type='text' name='mytext'>"+"<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this,this.parentNode.parentNode)'></div>";
        div4.innerHTML += "<br><br> <div><input type='text' name='mytext'>"+"<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this,this.parentNode.parentNode)'></div>";
    }

    function removeRow(input,parent)
    {
        parent.removeChild(input.parentNode);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

removeRow function
Here is a working example.

Comment: ya it will happen only in the first column if add the delete code for second column means the row was not been deleted so please give me a solution

Comment: @raji kumarJust added a second parameter in the removeRow(this,this.parentNode.parentNode) function.It works correct now

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `removeRow()` function to be like this:

```
function removeRow(input)
{
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input.previousSibling);
}
```

This removes just the input box and leaves the delete button, as you want it to.

***Edit***

To remove both the input box and the button:

```
function removeRow(input)
{
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input.previousSibling);
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
}
```

Comment: Hey che-azeh what my requirement is if i click the delete button means the entire row need to be deleted so please give me a solution for me

Comment: @rajikumar, everything including the text box and the button itself?

Comment: ya everythin was included in textbox and the delete button itselt

Comment: hey super man its working fine and i need a slight change if the entire row was deleted means the div was tag was need to go the normal stage so please help me

Comment: @rajikumar, I don't quite understand. Could you please be more explicit, or edit your original question? :-)

Comment: k everything was working fine could you please explain the code in the removeRow() i.e.                                                                             function removeRow(input)
{
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input.previousSibling);
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
}

Comment: `input` is the button. The code says "delete the previous sibling of `input` and then delete `input` itself"

Comment: Hey Thank u che-azeh thak u for gining the solution for me

Comment: i've one more doubt che-azeh how to add the Textox in a div without using the id of the div instead of that ID i need to use Class to add the textbox dynamically so please give me a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

There are many undefined variables in your code.Hope you are trying to refer to the `id`

```
// Array of ids
var divIds = ['div1','div2','div3','div4'];
function Add(){ 
divIds.forEach(function(item){  // loop & add html string to each of element
 document.getElementById(''+item+'').innerHTML ="<br><br><input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
})
}

//input.parentNode.childNodes will retun array of 4 elements, 2 br and 2 input
// need to remove first input
function removeRow(input) { 
   input.parentNode.childNodes[2].remove();
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/u7gdatgj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Dynamic Form</title>
            <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <style>
            #Wrapper {
                width: 90%;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #div1 {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                background: lightblue;
            }

            #div2 {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                background: lightyellow;
            }

            #div3 {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                background: lightgray;
            }

            #div4 {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                background: lightblue;
            }

            #ClearFix {
                clear: both;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>


                <button onclick="Add()">Add TextBox</button>

                <div id="Wrapper">
                    <div id="div1">
                        <p>This is Div one</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="div2">
                        <p>This is Div two</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="div3">
                        <p>This is Div three</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="div4">
                        <p>This is Div Four</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="ClearFix"></div>
                </div>

                <script>
                                function Add()
                                {
                                    div1.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext' id='input_div1'>"+"<input type='button' id='div1' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
                                    div2.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext' id='input_div2'>"+"<input type='button' id='div2' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
                                    div3.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext' id='input_div3'>"+"<input type='button' id='div3' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
                                    div4.innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext' id='input_div4'>"+"<input type='button' id='div4' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
                                }

                                function removeRow(input)
                                {
                                        var id = $(input).attr("id");
                                        $('#input_'+id).remove();
                            //          $('#'+id).remove();
                                }
                                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: i need only the solution in javascript so please give me a solution in javascript

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you. Make these changes in your javascript

```
// Array of ids
var divIds = ['div1','div2','div3','div4'];
function Add(){ 
   divIds.forEach(function(item){  
   // loop & add html string to each of element
   document.getElementById(''+item+'').innerHTML ="<br><br><input type='text' name='mytext'>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
 })
}
function removeRow(input) { 
   input.parentNode.childNodes[2].remove();  // removes text box
   input.parentNode.childNodes[3].remove();  // removes delete button
}
```