# How to delete the row in a div without using table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys this was my source code i need to delete the Row in a Div when i press the delete button using javascript so please give me a solution for me.The most important thing is we don't use Table instead of Div .So please give me a solution for me.

```js
function Add() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".div1");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext'>";
  }
}

function del() {
  var y = document.querySelectorAll(".div2");
  var i;
  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].innerHTML += "<br><br><br> <input type='button' value='delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'>";
  }
}


function removeRow(input) {
  input.parentNode.removeChild(input.previousSibling);
  input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
}
```

```css
#add_Btn {
  float: left;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 72%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
body {
  background: #00ffff;
}
input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0px 25px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=button] {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00ff99;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#Wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 7% auto;
}
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: #4dffc3;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightyellow;
}
#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightgray;
}
#div4 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: lightblue;
}
#ClearFix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section id="Wrapper">
  <button id="add_Btn" onclick="Add(); del();">Add TextBox</button><br><br>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div threee</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div Four</p>
  </div>
  <span class="div2">
    <p>This is Div Five</p>
  </span>
  <!--<div id="ClearFix"></div>-->
</section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete the Textbox dynamically in a DIV using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609352/how-to-delete-the-textbox-dynamically-in-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Looks like each div is a table _cell_, not a row. So you want to delete every div, effectively?

Comment: This seems to me like a request, not a question

Answer (score 0):

You must create a class for each line and remove by class,

see example below how to reach

```js
var cpt = 0;
    function Add()
    {
            var x = document.querySelectorAll(".div1");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
            {
                x[i].innerHTML += "<br><br> <input type='text' name='mytext' class='"+cpt+"'>";
            }
    }

    function del()
    {
        var y = document.querySelectorAll(".div2");
        var i;
        for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
        {
            y[i].innerHTML += "<br><br><br> <input type='button' value='delete'  class='"+cpt+"' onclick='removeRow("+cpt+")'>";
        }
  cpt++;
    }


    function removeRow(input)
    {
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName(input);
  for(var i = list.length - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
  if(list[i] && list[i].parentElement)
  list[i].parentElement.removeChild(list[i]);
    }
```

```css
    #add_Btn
        {
            float:left;
            margin:0% 0% 0% 72%;
            border-radius: 25px;
            cursor:pointer;
            padding:10px;
        }

    body
    {
        background: #00ffff;
    }

    input[type=text]
    {
        padding: 5px;
        margin:5px 0px 25px 0px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    input[type=button]
    {
        padding: 5px;
        margin:5px 0px 25px 0px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background:#00ff99;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    #Wrapper
        {
            width:80%;
            margin:7% auto;
        }

        .div1
        {
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            background:#4dffc3;
        }


        .div2
        {
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            background:lightyellow;
        }

        #div3
        {
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            background:lightgray;
        }

        #div4
        {
            float: left;
            width:20%;
            background:lightblue;
        }

        #ClearFix
        {
            clear:both;
        }
```

```html
<section id="Wrapper">

        <button id="add_Btn" onclick="Add(cpt); del(cpt);">Add TextBox</button>


        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is Div one</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is Div two</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is Div threee</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is Div Four</p>
        </div>

        <span class="div2">
            <p>This is Div Five</p>
        </span>
        <!--<div id="ClearFix"></div>-->
    </section>
```

Comment: Divs become more and more bigger after adding and deleting elements.

Comment: Remove the **<br/>**

Answer (score 0):

Update code by [@HassanSaghir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630980/4306572). Remove `<br/>` from js and fix css a bit.

```js
var cpt = 0;

function Add() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".div1");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='mytext' class='" + cpt + "'>";
    }
}

function del() {
    var y = document.querySelectorAll(".div2");
    var i;
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].innerHTML += "<input type='button' value='delete'  class='" + cpt + "' onclick='removeRow(" + cpt + ")'>";
    }
    cpt++;
}


function removeRow(input) {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName(input);
    for (var i = list.length - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
        if (list[i] && list[i].parentElement)
            list[i].parentElement.removeChild(list[i]);
}
```

```css
#add_Btn {
    float: left;
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 72%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}
body {
    background: #00ffff;
}
input {
  display: block; /* new */
}
input[type=text] {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 25px 0px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=button] {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 25px 0px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #00ff99;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#Wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 7% auto;
}
.div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #4dffc3;
}
.div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: lightyellow;
}
#div3 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: lightgray;
}
#div4 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: lightblue;
}
#ClearFix {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section id="Wrapper">
  <button id="add_Btn" onclick="Add(cpt); del(cpt);">Add TextBox</button>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div threee</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is Div Four</p>
  </div>
  <span class="div2">
    <p>This is Div Five</p>
  </span>
  <!--<div id="ClearFix"></div>-->
</section>
```

Comment: could you please explain the process at removeRow()

Comment: When you add inputs by clicking 'Add' button you insert inputs with same class names: '0', '1', '2' per click.
Function `removeRow()` calls with parameter - class name of input.
It gets list of all inputs with same class name - `document.getElementsByClassName(input);`. Then it goes through array of inputs `for (var i = list.length - 1; 0 <= i; i--)`. If input has parent `list[i].parentElement`, it calls its parent method to delete child (i.e. input) `list[i].parentElement.removeChild(list[i])`.

Comment: oh thank you for giving this information and finally would please explain how the variable "var cpt" was perform in the program and please explain what is the usage of increament of "cpt++"